# How to handle URL links in text data while preprocessing data in NLP

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nlp, preprocessor

I have a data frame that has a column with URL links in it. Can someone tell me how to handle these links while pre-processing data in NLP?
For eg, the df column looks similar to this-

```
  likes      text 
   11        https://www.facebook.com
   12        https://www.facebook.com
   13        https://www.facebook.com
   14        Good morning
   15        How are.....you?
```

Do we need to remove these URL links completely or is there another way to deal with them?

Comment: That depends entirely on your usecase.

Comment: I would agree that it depends on your use-case. I’d also look into whatever package you’re interested in using and see if removing URLs are part of their preprocessing step. If not, the solution requires looking at whether or not there are URLs embedded within text you care about, or if rows contain either text or URLs only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter out the URLs, as they are not natural language.
Shouldn't be too hard to write such a predicate,
perhaps something as simple as `str(word).startswith('http')` would suffice.
Or use a regex:

```
import re


url_re = re.compile(r'^https?://', re.IGNORECASE)


def is_url(word):
    return url_re.search(word) is not None


def keep_row(row):
    return not is_url(row['text'])


df = df[df.apply(keep_row, axis=1)]
```